# Is there any function like ap2, ap3 in arrow-kt?

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

I saw scala code using [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/) in this [post](https://mostafa-asg.github.io/post/practical-scala-cats-applicative-functor/).

```scala
val a = Some(7)
val b = Some(9)
Applicative[Option].ap2(Some(add))(a,b)
```

And I tried migrating this code to kotlin and arrow like following.

```
Option.applicative()
        .tupled(Some(7), Some(9))
        .ap(Some(::add))

// works but dirty
fun add(tuple: Tuple2<Int, Int>): Int = tuple.a + tuple.b

// not work, compilation error
// fun add(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
```

As you noticed, `Tuple2` must be specified in the `add` function signature.
I searched the official document of arrow, but there is no `apN` function like ap2, ap3, ap4.

**Is there any way to use the second function which not included `Tuple2` type?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once version 0.10 is available Arrow will have a `.tupled()` method on function types that handles this, so you will be able to write:

```
Option.applicative()
      .tupled(Some(7), Some(9))
      .ap(::add.tupled())

fun add(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
```

for functions of up to 22 arguments.

Comment: Hi, I know it's been three years since you wrote this answer, but I'm looking for the exact same thing now, and can't find `.tupled()` in arrow-kt. Do you know if its name was changed or if it was removed completely?